# Can not use composer for installing amnah user for yii2

Tags: yii2

i want to use amnah-yii2 user but i could not use the composer to install it. when i run composer this error occure.

Could not open input file: composer.phar

Regards

Comment: Have you got composer installed at all?

Comment: yes, i did alreay!  actully i did not undrestand how to install composer and then install amnah!  if you can guide me it will be great.

Comment: For instruction how to install composer follow the guide at [getcomposer.org](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)

Comment: Composer successfully installed to: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/OPS/test/basic/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
Some settings on your machine may cause stability issues with Composer.
If you encounter issues, try to change the following:

The OpenSSL library (0.9.8zc) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1.
If possible you should upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or above.

Nezamuddins-MacBook-Pro:basic nezamuddin$ php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
Nezamuddins-MacBook-Pro:basic nezamuddin$

Comment: as i said i already installed the composer let me run the amnah using composer and show you the errors

Comment: i run this commond:   Nezamuddins-MacBook-Pro:basic nezamuddin$  composer "amnah/yii2-user": "^5.0"   and this was the error:  composer: command not found